# How to deal with values that deferring only because of case in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I merged to similar datasets and as a result of that merge a lot of my values has the same value but different cases. I'm trying to find a way to fix those values in the most pythonic way.

For example I have a Armed column and it's unique vals are:

```
array([nan, 'Gun', 'Knife', 'Unarmed', 'Toy weapon', 'gun', 'unarmed',
       'toy weapon', 'nail gun', 'knife', 'shovel', 'hammer', 'hatchet',
       'undetermined', 'sword', 'machete', 'box cutter', 'metal object',
       'screwdriver', 'lawn mower blade', 'flagpole',
       'guns and explosives', 'cordless drill', 'crossbow', 'metal pole',
       'Taser', 'metal pipe', 'metal hand tool', 'blunt object',
       'metal stick', 'sharp object', 'meat cleaver', 'carjack',
       "contractor's level", 'chain', 'unknown weapon', 'stapler',
       'beer bottle', 'bean-bag gun', 'baseball bat and fireplace poker',
       'straight edge razor', 'gun and knife', 'ax', 'brick',
       'baseball bat', 'hand torch', 'chain saw', 'garden tool',
       'scissors', 'pole', 'pick-axe', 'flashlight', 'baton', 'spear',
       'chair', 'pitchfork', 'hatchet and gun', 'rock', 'piece of wood',
       'bayonet', 'pipe', 'glass shard', 'motorcycle', 'pepper spray',
       'metal rake', 'crowbar', 'oar', 'machete and gun', 'tire iron',
       'air conditioner', 'pole and knife', 'baseball bat and bottle',
       'fireworks', 'pen', 'chainsaw', 'gun and sword', 'gun and car',
       'vehicle', 'pellet gun', 'claimed to be armed', 'BB gun',
       'incendiary device', 'samurai sword', 'bow and arrow',
       'gun and vehicle', 'vehicle and gun', 'wrench', 'walking stick',
       'barstool', 'BB gun and vehicle', 'wasp spray', 'air pistol',
       'Airsoft pistol', 'baseball bat and knife', 'vehicle and machete'],
      dtype=object)
```

As you can see they are pretty much copied but one is Capital and the other is all lower cased.

Answer (score 0):

If by "fix" you mean removing duplicates, I'd suggest converting both arrays to lowercase prior to the merge.

Here are some examples:

```
>>> [x.lower() for x in ["A","B","C"]]
['a', 'b', 'c']

>>> df['x_lowercase'] = df['x'].str.lower()
```